# Exclamation mark in Julia "!" after function in scripts

Tags: arrays, julia, differentialequations.jl, composite-types

I am trying to save multiple solutions of my ODE in an Array. Right now this is what I got:

```
sols = []
for i in 1:numSim
  if solver == "Rosenbrock23"
    solution = solve(odeprob, Rosenbrock23())
    append!(sols, solution)
  end
end
```

As you can see I only want to append to this Array, if a certain ode solver is used. However, the "append!" statement neglects this statement and runs every iteration of the loop. I tried preallocating the array sol, to use a statement like this:`sols[i] = solution`
But here im struggling with the type declaration of the array sol.

I tried
`sols = zeros(length)`

and then
`sols[i] = solution`

However solution is of type ODESolution and can not be converted to Float64

Answer (score 0):

Please provide adequate information to get an exact answer. I can't reproduce your problem since you didn't mention what is `odeprob` or the value of `numSim`. Since you declared `sols = []` then the `eltype` of `sols` should be `Any`; hence it should be capable to contain any element.
However, I can replicate the [code in the official doc (Example 1 : Solving Scalar Equations (ODE))](https://docs.sciml.ai/DiffEqDocs/stable/tutorials/ode_example/#Example-1-:-Solving-Scalar-Equations), and combine it with your approach:

```
using DifferentialEquations

f(u,p,t) = 1.01*u
u0 = 1/2
tspan = (0.0,1.0)
odeprob = ODEProblem(f,u0,tspan)

sols = []
numSim = 2
solver = "Rosenbrock23"
for i in 1:numSim
  if solver == "Rosenbrock23"
    solution = solve(odeprob, Rosenbrock23())
    append!(sols, solution)
  end
end
```

Then if I call the `sols` variable:

```
julia> sols
22-element Vector{Any}:
 0.5
 0.5015852274675505
 0.5177172276935554
 0.5423763076371255
 0.5852018498590001
 0.6425679823795596
 0.7275742030693312
 0.835930076418226 
 0.9846257728490266
 1.1713401410831334
 1.3738764155543854
 0.5
 0.5015852274675505
 0.5177172276935554
 0.5423763076371255
 0.5852018498590001
 0.6425679823795596
 0.7275742030693312
 0.835930076418226
 0.9846257728490266
 1.1713401410831334
 1.3738764155543854
```